# VBScript execting wScript not executing properly

Tags: vbscript, wsh

Attempting to automate loading in my IIS logs into MSSQL, I have written the following function.

Executing this function causes a cmd prompt to pop up to execute the logparser.exe and then it immediately closes. It stays open long enough for me to see the logparser help menu.

However, if I remove the " >> test.out" portion, it works as expected.

Any idea why? As you see I am outputting the shell string which comes out formed properly as expected.

```
Function RunLogParser(logFile) 

Dim oShell, iRC, ShellString 

WScript.Echo "Importing File " + logFile + vbCrLf



ShellString = """C:\Program Files\Log Parser 2.2\LogParser.exe"" ""SELECT * INTO weblog FROM " + logFile + """ " + " -i:W3C -o:SQL -server:localhost -database:testdb -driver:""SQL Server"" -createTable:OFF" + " >> test.out"



WScript.Echo vbTab + "Shell String " + ShellString + vbCrLf



     Set oShell =  WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")



     iRC = oShell.Run(Shellstring, 1, True)        




     RunLogParser = (iRC=0)



RunLogParser = False

End Function
```

Comment: Try Unding cscript instand of wsript

Answer (score 0):

To use a shell feature (>> redirection) you need a shell; so prepend "%comspec% /c " to your ShellString. Due to the complexity of this command, further tinkering with quotes may be necessary.

Comment: Please provide an example? I tried this but it did not work:

ShellString = "%comspec% /c " + """C:\Program Files\Log Parser 2.2\LogParser.exe""